# how to add delivery delay on AWS SQS messages using Spring JmsTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-sqs, jmstemplate

Hi I want to implement the function like sending sqs messages with a specific delivery delay using java and JmsTemplate.
Actually, I finished the implementation of sending messages without delay.
like this:

```
    @Override
    public boolean sendMessage(String queueName, String message) throws EventBrokerException {
        final String messageWithTransactionGuid = addTransactionGuidToMessage(message);
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queueName, messageWithTransactionGuid);
        return isSuccess;
    }
```

I read some articles, Maybe I need to do somthing like this???

```
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queueName, messageWithTransactionGuid, new MessagePostProcessor() {
            @Override
            public Message postProcessMessage(Message message) throws JMSException {
                message.setIntProperty(/*specify field name and delay seconds*/);
                return message;
            }
        });
```

But I didn't see any examples, I read the sourcecode and didn't find out what to specify, can anybody help?

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Comment: @IgorDonin see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what I did is a simple way:

```
    private Boolean doSendMessage(String queueName, String message, long deliveryDelay){

        jmsTemplate.setDeliveryDelay(deliveryDelay); 
       jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queueName, message);
        jmsTemplate.setDeliveryDelay(DEFAULT_MESSAGE_DELIVERY_DELAY);
        return isSuccess;
    }
```

Here `DEFAULT_MESSAGE_DELIVERY_DELAY` is -1.

I injected jsmTemplate, and setDeliveryDelay and resetDeliveryDelay

Comment: Does this not risk a race condition if multiple threads call this function at once?

Comment: So the setDeliveryDelay takes inseconds ?